# Hidden Form Field?

Tags: html

```
<form action="/action.php">
<input type="textbox" name="Username" readonly value=" ' . $user->username . ' ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="selected">
<input type="submit" value="submit"></form>
```

I want to hide the textbox input of the form from the user? The text box automatically collects the username of the logged in user of my website but i don't want to show it to them..It looks awkward. How to achieve hide it? Is there a way out?

Answer (score 10):

Well, just make it `hidden` then

```
<input type="hidden" name="Username" readonly value=" ' . $user->username . ' ">
```

They can still see it in the source code though

Comment: the username value doesn't get collected in the database?

Comment: It will still work the same as if it was a text field. This value will still be posted like the other values on the form, it just wont show. That's a standard HTML field type

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="Username" value=" ' . $user->username . ' ">
```