# change amount charged using Different Objects to look for price

Tags: javascript, mongodb, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe to create a way to accept payments on my website but i want the price to be changed depending on wat object in my catalog i load. My show page pulls data from mongo as objects so within my object I have different fields and within the object i have the field i want to pass into my strip.charges.create({}); SO this is wat my charge page looks like i got it from stripe docs:

```
app.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
    var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;

    //console.log("print the price "+req.data.price);
    console.log("print the price "+data.price2);
    console.log("print the price "+req.params.price);
    console.log("print the price "+req.params.amount);
    console.log("print the price "+req.body(JSON.stringify(data)));
    //console.log("print the price "+JSON.stringify(req.data.price));
    var amount = 1122;<= i want to make this change depending on wat item i load into the show page is there a function call like anything similiar to what i have tried above on my console.logs 

    stripe.charges.create({
        card: stripeToken,
        currency: 'usd',
        amount: amount
    },
    function(err, charge) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(500, err);
        } else {
            res.send(204);
        }
    });
});
```

right now my amount is static and regardless on what item i click on in my catalog itll always charge 11.22 instead of the price needed to be charged. is there a way to implement this?

Comment: will need to figure this out client side so token matches amount that was sent from there to stripe

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to send a hidden `<input>` element along with your form to indicate which product ID they're buying, and then you can use that to look up the price in your datastore.

Comment: how do u send hidden input attached to the form?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968741/hidden-form-field