# How can i move value from angular form to server nodejs

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, stripe-payments

```
      - This is the html:
      <body ng-controller="stripeController">
      <form action="/stripe" method="POST" id="payment-form">
      <span class="payment-errors"></span>
      <div class="from-row">
       <lebel>
           <span>Price:{{getTotal}}$</span>
           <input type="hidden" data-stripe="number">
       </lebel>
   </div>

   <div class="form-row">
       <label>
           <span>Card Number</span>
           <input type="number" size="20" data-stripe="number">
       </label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-row">
       <label>
           <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
           <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
       </label>
       <span> / </span>
       <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
   </div>

   <div class="form-row">
       <label>
           <span>CVC</span>
           <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
       </label>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
     </form>
     </body>
```

- This is the controller code:

  ```
   app.controller('stripeController', function($scope, $http) { 
   $http.get('/api/me').success(function (response) {
     $scope.userInfo = response;
     $scope.isCartEmpty = true;
     $scope.userCart = [];
     if($scope.userInfo.cart.length>0){
         $scope.isCartEmpty= false;
     }
     console.log($scope.isCartEmpty);
     for(var i=0;i<$scope.userInfo.cart.length;i++){
         $scope.userCart[i] = $scope.userInfo.cart[i].productId
     }
     var y = 0;
     $scope.getTotal =0;

     for(i=0;i<$scope.userCart.length;i++) {
         $http.get('/api/product/' + $scope.userCart[i]).success(function
     (response) {
             $scope.userInfo.cart[y].name = response.name;
             $scope.userInfo.cart[y].price = response.price;
             $scope.getTotal+= response.price;
             y++;
           });

         }

      });
  ```

  });
- This is the  node.js post function :

  ```
  router.post('/stripe', function(req, res){
   //Need to check if the cart empty than re-direct to catalog.
   var stripe = require("stripe")(
       "sk_test_mypass"
   );

   stripe.charges.create({
       amount: ????? * 100,
       currency: "usd",
       source: req.body.stripeToken, // obtained with Stripe.js
       description: "Test Charge"
       }, function(err, charge) {
       if(err){
         console.log("Error");
       }
     console.log("Successfully bought product!");

     });

    });
  ```

  -I have 1 questions:
      In the node.js function where I put "?????" how can I get data from the 
      html form. When I type req.body.getTotal I don't get the data...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to send it in a [hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968741/hidden-form-field), but it would be better to calculate the total from the product IDs and quantities in the Cart on the server side so there's no opportunity for the amount to be changed client side.